# PhpStorm .vue pug styling

Tags: vue.js, pug, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, phpstorm-2017.1

Is anyone getting issues with syntax highlighting for `.vue` files within PhpStorm when using pug?

Is this something that it only available in WebStorm and not planning on coming to PhpStorm?

Within PhpStorm my view file looks like the following:

[image]

I have the following plugins installed:
`.ignore, AngularJS, Apache config (.htaccess) support, ASP, BashSupport, Behat Support, Blade Support, Bootstrap 3, Codeception Framework, CoffeeScript, Color Ide, Command Line Tool Support, Copyright, CSS Support, CSSReorder (beta), CVS Integration, Database Tools and SQL, Docker integration, Drupal Support, EditorConfig, EJS, File Watchers, Gherkin, Git Integration, GitHub, GNU GetText files support (*.po), Go Lang Plugin, Google App Engine Support for PHP, Haml, hg4idea, HTML Tools, Ini4Idea, IntelliLang, JavaScript Debugger, JavaScript Intention Power Pack, JavaScript Support, Joomla! Support, Karma, Less support, Markdown Navigator, Markdown support, Material Theme UI, NodeJS, Perforce Integration, Performance Testing, Phing Support, PHP Docker, PHP Remote Interpreter, PHPSpec BDD Framework, PhpStorm Workshop, Pug (ex-Jade), QuirksMode, Refactor-X, Remote Hosts Access, REST Client, ReStructuredText Support, Sass support, Settings Repository, SSH Remote Run, Stylus support, Subversion Integration, Task Management, Terminal, TextMate bundles support, Time Tracking, tslint, Twig Support, UML Support, Vagrant, Vue.js, W3C Validators, WordPress Support, XPathView + XSLT Support, XSLT-Debugger, YAML`

If I open the same file within WebStorm it highlights as expected.

[image]

Im running Phpstorm 2017.1.4 & Vue.js plugin is version 171.4424.63. I have removed the Vue.js plugin and re-installed it a number of times with no luck.

Comment: JetBrains also has a support forum for PhpStorm perhaps you can get an answer there a bit faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @lena

Within (Settings | Editor | File Types) *.vue was not listed.

I had a section called Vue.js Templates but it empty with no Registered Patterns. Adding *.vue in there fixed my issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

it works in PHPStorm just in the same way as in Webstorm:

[image]

from your screenshot it seems that you have the wrong (old) Vue.js plugin installed. what PhpStorm version do you work with?

Comment: Im running Phpstorm 2017.1.4.

The version of the Vue.js plugin i have is 171.4424.63. 

I removed this plugin and re-installed it and get the same version still with the highlighting error described above.

Comment: I removed this plugin and re-installed it and get the same version still with the highlighting error described above. The Vue.js plugin is listed under the 'install JetBrains plugins' section an its the only one listed.

Comment: what file type (Settings | Editor | File Types) is `*.vue* pattern associated with?

Comment: Thanks that fixed it !!